# purim-torah-in-jest tag

Tags: discussion, specific-tag

Should the [purim-torah-in-jest](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/purim-torah-in-jest) tag be only for *Purim torah* questions meant in jest, or also for questions about *Purim torah*?

For some history, see:

- [the comments on the question "the danger of eating matza"](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/5963)
- [the revision history of the question "Purim Torah - Heresy"](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/6306/revisions)

Comment: If I understood correctly, and these are *joke* questions, should they even be on the site at all? We closed [riddles], why not jokes?

Comment: @AviD: ["We do prefer that questions on Stack Overflow stay on the topic of programming, but as Joel and I have discussed before on the podcast, this is somewhat subjective, and it’s OK to err on the side of 'fun' every now and then. Not all the time, mind you, but occasional peripherally related digressions that the community enjoys (and upvotes) are perfectly fine."](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/11/stack-overflow-is-you/)

Comment: that is a veerryy old post, relative to SO... those types of questions are now shunned on SO. That said, what SO does and what [judaism.se] does, do not have to be the same... my point was that if you're allowing "fun" questions, shouldnt riddles be allowed? and if not, then neither should jokes... Eifa v'eifa, and all that ;)

Comment: @AviD Whether and how to permit joke questions at all is a question worthy of another meta post and not automatically resolved by the apparent communal consensus regarding riddles. The two have some of the same issues and benefits, but not the exact same.

Answer (score 2):

IMO it's good to have a tag that distinguishes the questions meant in jest from the others so people (who catch on) can distinguish the one set of questions from the other.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming we're willing to permit in-jest questions in some way (which is a question worthy of its own meta-post, as I indicated in the comments):

- I agree with [msh210](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/255/purim-torah-in-jest-tag/256#256) that it ought to be made very clear that such questions are in this category and are not to be taken seriously. That is, as [WAF](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/255/purim-torah-in-jest-tag/259#259) indicates, what [purim-torah-in-jest](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/purim-torah-in-jest) has been used for to date.
- If you think that there ought to be a tag *about* Purim Torah and/or jokes in general, then let's create one, [re]name it and [purim-torah-in-jest](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/purim-torah-in-jest) to best reflect their respective contents in tag names, write wikis for both that make it very clear what each is for and which has content that shouldn't be taken seriously, and re-tag all existing joke and about-joke questions accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that that tag has been used historically almost exclusively for questions which themselves comprise "Purim Torah", but that makes it a very peculiar tag. Every other tag (that I can think of) refers to the subject matter of the question, not the type of question. Although I wouldn't move to obliterate the tag on techinical grounds like this (or principled grounds like taking exception to joke questions), I think questions *about* Purim Torah are more accurately and consistently referred to by this tag than any other and should therefore be maintained.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe we should have a "Joke" tag. Would it also be possible to have someone verify that their question is indeed a joke before applying the tag, so someone doesn't later come along and ask "Are there jokes in the Torah?"

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/21874/9682