# Limited Purim Torah Questions

Tags: discussion, policy, close-reasons, purim-torah-policy

In response to Isaac Moses's last question [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/772/759):

[This question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/14546/759) was recently asked as a Purim torah question. I am sorely tempted to vote to close it as too localized. IMO the kinds of Purim torah questions that are in scope are those that are general enough to let many people answer in lots of fun and unusual ways. Questions that, while funny, do not lend themselves to more than one answer are not useful as we are not trying to host a collection of one-lined Jewish jokes. We are trying to stimulate fun discussion about Torah "issues" where people can use their creativity to participate. I note that [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/14543/759) received 5 independently funny answers within 3 hours of being asked. [This question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/5963/759) too received many varied and funny responses. I know there is a fine line between what is and is not too specific, but that would be for the community to decide: it takes 5 votes to close a question.

So, do people think this is an appropriate use of closing for "too localized"?

Comment: I think there are too many already

Comment: It's gone **.**

Comment: So it is........

Answer (score 3):

"Too localized" is no longer a standard closure reason, but, yes, I agree such questions should be closed, say as "unclear what you're asking". We've closed some already.