# Purim torah activity compared to normal activity on the site

Tags: discussion, purim-torah-policy, site-statistics

Related to a comment to [Limited Purim Torah Questions](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/834/limited-purim-torah-questions), can we please know how many Purim Torah questions have been posted compared to the normal number of questions posted to the site in a similar period?

Comment: Can't you just count the number of questions here: [tag:purim-torah-in-jest]?

Comment: @DoubleAA that would cover all years, and doesn't address the comparison part.  It seems like a good answer to this would be a Data Explorer query that gets the total number of new questions during a time period and the number of those that are on the PT tag.

Comment: @MonicaCellio It's pretty easy to see which questions were from which years if sorted by 'newest'.

Comment: That's true; they'll fall into clumps.  Getting the number of other questions asked during those specific time periods is harder, though, hence the SEDE suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [a query jointly edited by myself and Isaac Moses](http://data.stackexchange.com/judaism/query/173030/ptij-comparer), we have these data:

---

February 10–27, 2013 saw 33 PTIJ questions posted. (That was, roughly, the 2013 period in which PTIJ questions were allowed.)

---

January 10–27, 2013 saw 123 non-PTIJ questions posted.

February 10–27, 2013 saw 144 non-PTIJ questions posted.

March 10–27, 2013 saw 189 non-PTIJ questions posted.

April 10–27, 2013 saw 174 non-PTIJ questions posted.

May 10–27, 2013 saw 131 non-PTIJ questions posted.

June 10–27, 2013 saw 132 non-PTIJ questions posted.

July 10–27, 2013 saw 129 non-PTIJ questions posted.

August 10–27, 2013 saw 108 non-PTIJ questions posted.

September 10–27, 2013 saw 129 non-PTIJ questions posted.

October 10–27, 2013 saw 135 non-PTIJ questions posted.

November 10–27, 2013 saw 131 non-PTIJ questions posted.

December 10–27, 2013 saw 148 non-PTIJ questions posted.

Comment: Average questions Month 10-27 = 139.4        ...        PTIJ for Feb 10 - 27 = 24%.

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok also of note: February's non-PTIJ count for those days was similar to the average across all months, suggesting that PTIJ activity didn't have a significant negative effect (e.g. through distraction) on serious contribution levels.

Comment: @IsaacMoses Yes - important point.