# PSA: Purim Torah In Jest is just that - in jest.

Tags: discussion, purim-torah-policy

Purim Torah posts, I’ve noticed, have been getting a lot of downvotes lately. While [earlier](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/89463/ptij-is-super-mario-odyssey-a-basar-bchalav-issue#comment289571_89463) I had expressed this thought, [echoed by ezra there](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/89463/ptij-is-super-mario-odyssey-a-basar-bchalav-issue#comment289573_89463), I’m starting to think it’s because not everyone is getting into the holiday spirit.

Going through the review queue, I’m seeing posts like [this one](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/32738) getting flagged for deletion. A short post isn’t always bad - it’s quality, not quantity. That answer delivers IMO a great punchline to the original joke, and I see no reason to have it deleted. As of writing, nobody else has voted to trash it, either.

This post serves two purposes: to remind people to have fun and not to take anything labeled PTIJ so seriously ([ahem, ezra](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/89463/ptij-is-super-mario-odyssey-a-basar-bchalav-issue#comment289482_89463)), and to receive other people’s input on what else may be causing this negative reaction to PTIJ and what we, as a community, can do to help reverse it.

Comment: see https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/834/759 and https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3490/759 Not all comedy is good comedy. Writing good comedy is an art form. Purim Torah season is not a free for all to post anything, and voting is still supposed to be used to push good content up and bad content down.

Comment: I, ezra, sincerely apologize for ruining your Purim spirit. :) :) :)

Comment: Note that the system may automatically flag short answers to the LQP review queue without human interference.

Answer (score 9):

[image: Cartoon with the words "NOT SURE IF THEY'RE NOT IN THE PURIM SPIRIT / OR THAT JOKE JUST WASN'T FUNNY"]

Comment: Yes, exactly. Voting on PTIJ is, very rightly, also about if it is funny.

Answer (score 8):

The PTIJ questions are supposed to be in jest, yes, but that doesn't mean they're exempt from all the other requirements of a Mi Yodeya question. Thus, they should include enough background info for people to understand the question; should be real, answerable questions; and should exemplify *d'racheha darche noam*. In addition, they should follow [the PTIJ rules](/q/797):

> It's gotta be distinctly **"Purim"** (not serious), distinctly **Torah**, and distinctly **Q&A**. Purim Torah questions that don't have all three of these qualities may be closed.
>
> So, post sincere-*looking* **questions** (you know, the kind that invite **answers**) that:
>
> - **misinterpret** a real **Torah** concept or Jewish text
>
> or
>
> - apply a distinctly **Torah** style (e.g. Talmudic analysis) to an **irrelevant** topic

The requirements imposed on a PTIJ question are thus stricter than those on a normal question, so it's no wonder that it's easier to fail to meet those requirements (in the view of the voter) and to garner down-, close-, and delete-votes.

(Plus, people might downvote if they think the joke is weak.)

Oh, and the same applies, mutatis mutandis, to answers.