# Downvoting PTIJ That Isn't Funny

Tags: discussion, purim-torah-policy, voting

Is it appropriate to downvote Purim Torah posts that aren't creative or funny?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4532/2

Comment: I think the answer is yes.

Comment: @isaac agreed, I marked as a dupe