# Should we add "PTIJ:" in the title of all Purim Torah questions?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, purim-torah-policy

Should there be a rule to have to add "PTIJ:" before the title on all Purim Torah questions? This way it seems that people won't click on a question without overlooking the fact it's a Purim Torah.

Comment: I think this is something that some people have done in the past, but it seems like people should be able to tell from the question's tag that it's PTIJ.

Comment: @Daniel You can't see tags easily on mobile or in the related question list or the hot network questions list or with an rss reader or...

Comment: When I'm looking for serious issues, the flood of PTIJ questions can sometimes get annoying. I think prepending the title is a good way to be able to visually skip over them and not waste time when someone is not looking for PT.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) Ok we're implementing this. Please do this for all new questions. (Don't bump an old question just for this, but if you are bumping it anyway then go ahead and do this too.)

---

I suggested this at https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3838/759

It is currently voted +10/-3.

I still strongly support it. How does it hurt to be more clear?

Comment: Agreed. It never hurts to be more clear.