# Should we revisit the “no other tag” Purim Torah policy?

Tags: discussion, tags, purim-torah-policy

As per the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/797/9682):

> Apply the tag [purim-torah-in-jest](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/purim-torah-in-jest) and no other tag.

Since we now [put PTIJ in front of all Purim Torah posts](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4507/9682), should we revisit this policy, since it’s now more obvious whether it’s PTIJ or not?

Comment: I know voting works differently on meta, so a -1 just means you disagree with me. That said, I’m curious why.

Comment: @mbloch I said nothing about removing the tag, nor did I say anything about editing old posts.

Comment: @mbloch Since we have PTIJ at the front of every post, I was proposing that we be allowed to use *additional* tags besides PTIJ.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't think we should revisit the tagging policy.

Firstly, we should keep things uniform as much as possible.

Secondly, if I'm searching for a tag, I don't want to have dozens of results that I cannot answer, and provide no useful information on the topic.

Thirdly, adding tags will allow users to get score for those tags, which to me is a bit misleading and unfair.  For example, if I see someone has a high score on the Halacha tag, I'm assuming it is because they have contributed useful Halacha questions and answers, not that they have come up with a cute joke.  This is especially relevant because Purim Torah scores and voting tend to be pretty high.

Comment: Ooh, tag score -- I hadn't thought of that.

Comment: Check mark just for point number 3.

Answer (score 5):

When somebody searches or uses tags to find questions about kashrut or a particular parsha or a minhag etc, I don't think the results should include Purim Torah questions.  The typical visitor from Google won't know what "PTIJ" means and shouldn't have to read through a question only to find out it's not serious.  Further, the misunderstandings upon which many Purim Torah questions rely could make us look bad ("wait, somebody on that site thinks *that's* what that word means??") to people who don't read through to the policy statement at the bottom.

Most of *us* know the deal.  Most of our readers aren't us.